# Testing parallel requests

Tags: javascript, rest, mocha.js, integration-testing, chai

I would like to test my web application by sending multiple chai requests(get,post) parallel to my REST Resources.

My intention is to test multitasking of several users which are accessing reports because I know that there are still some problems.

I can produce error manually by using the web-Application manually with 4-5 Tabs and different Users logged in making some refresh or other actions on reports.

But I can not manage it to produce this errors with my integration-Tests.

I tried a lot of things but now I do not have any further ideas and approaches.

My basic idea was to send multiple chai.requests to my ressources to produce the error - but no success. 
At first I thought the "await" Keyword is the problem but it was not.

Here you can see an example request to my ressources.

I would like to send request parallel to my web application but it seems that it is not possible with chai.request or is it? 
It seems that my request are processed sequentially.

All in all I send over 200 requests but I can not produce the error. Using the GUI manually I can produce it in one minute.

```
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            for (let j = 0; j < actions.length; j++) {
                try {
                    res = chai.request(Address)
                        .post(apiPath + '/report/' + rid[j]+)
                        .set('Authorization', users[j])
                        .send({
                            actions[j]
                        });
                } catch (error) {
                    res = error.res;
                }
                }
                }
```